# How $2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}$ and $\frac{3xyz}{x\sqrt{yz}+y\sqrt{zx}+z\sqrt{xy}}$ are related for $x,y,z \geq 0$?

Tags: inequality, means

The first expression is a heometric mean of pairwise harmonic means and obeys the following inequality:

$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq \color{blue}{ 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}} \geq  \frac{3xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$

The second expression is a harmonic mean of pairwise heometric means and obeys the same inequality:

$$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \geq \color{blue}{ \frac{3xyz}{x\sqrt{yz}+y\sqrt{zx}+z\sqrt{xy}}} \geq  \frac{3xyz}{xy+yz+zx}$$

> I want to know how these two expressions are related ($\leq$ or $\geq$) for $x,y,z \geq 0$ .

---

**Edit**

Since the realtion is homogenous, we can take $xyz=1$ without loss of generality, then we just need to compare:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} \text{ ? } \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}}{3}$$

Or rather:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+1/(xy))(1/(xy)+x)}}{2} \text{ ? } \frac{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{1/(xy)}}{3}$$

Comment: Looks like the one on the right is bigger, according to plot of Wolfram-alpha

Comment: @Emre, was it 1D or 2D plot?

Comment: 2D, $x=1$, $y,z$ between $0,2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will prove

$$\frac{3xyz}{x\sqrt{yz}+y\sqrt{zx}+z\sqrt{xy}}\ge 2 \sqrt[3]{\frac{x^2y^2z^2}{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}$$

Let $x=a^2,y=b^2,z=c^2$. Then, after taking third powers, our inequality becomes

$$\frac{27a^6b^6c^6}{(a+b+c)^3a^3b^3c^3}\ge 8{\frac{a^4b^4c^4}{(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)}}$$

After expanding, one needs to show

$$27(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\ge 8(a+b+c)^3abc\qquad (1)$$

or

$$27\sum_{sym}u^4v^2+54a^2b^2c^2\ge 4\sum_{sym}u^4vw+24\sum_{sym}u^3v^2w+48a^2b^2c^2$$
After canceling both sides, 
$$27\sum_{sym}u^4v^2+\sum_{sym}u^2v^2w^2\ge 4\sum_{sym}u^4vw+24\sum_{sym}u^3v^2w$$

By AM-GM, 
$$\sum_{sym}u^4v^2+\sum_{sym}u^2v^2w^2\ge \sum_{sym}u^3v^2w$$

And by Muirhead's inequality
$$\sum_{sym}u^4v^2\ge \sum_{sym}u^3v^2w$$
$$\sum_{sym}u^4v^2\ge \sum_{sym}u^4vw$$

Summing these all up gives us the desired result. Observe that $(1)$ can be proved in million different ways, I just like Muirhead's Inequality.

Comment: Thank you! I've already used your $(1)$ recently, so I'm familiar with it. Just didn't simplify the original expression enough

Comment: Is there a single-line proof for (1)?

Comment: don't know, sorry

Answer (score 1):

In Emre's solution, he transformed the problem into
$$27(a^2+b^2)(b^2+c^2)(c^2+a^2)\ge 8(a+b+c)^3abc\qquad (1)$$ 
and then proved this inequality by fully expanding it.

In this answer, I will give a simpler proof.

**Lemma.** For any $x,z,z\ge 0$ we have $$\begin{equation}
9(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx) \quad (1)
\end{equation}$$
*Proof.* True because 
$$LHS - RHS = \sum x(y^2+z^2) - 6xyz = \sum x(y-z)^2 \ge 0.$$

This well-known lemma is very useful in solving olympiad inequalities. I have mentioned it once [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1812595/prove-frac-sqrt3xyyzzx2-geq-sqrt-fracxyyzzx3-for/1816285#1816285).

Applying the lemma, $(1)$ is reduced to proving
$$24(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2) \ge 8(a+b+c)^3abc,$$
which follows directly from $3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2$ and $a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2 \ge abc(a+b+c)$ (the latter is $p^2+q^2+r^2 \ge pq+qr+rp$ with $p=ab,q=bc,r=ca$).

Comment: That's a standard "technique" in the books of VN olympiad !

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo It's a well-known lemma, not a technique, and  can be found in any references on Olympiad inequalities.

Comment: Sound like you know what you are doing in inequality. +1.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo Thanks for the +1 :D