# Prove $\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} \geq \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}}$ for $x,y,z \geq 0$

Tags: inequality, means

We have geometric mean of pairwise arithmetic means on the left, which obeys the following inequality:

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}  \geq \color{blue}{ \frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} } \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

And on the right we have root-mean-square of geometric means, obeying the same inequality:

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}  \geq \color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}} } \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

This time I checked with Wolfram Alpha first, and apparently, the inequality in the title is true for all $x,y,z \geq 0$:

$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} \geq \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}}$$

[image]

> How do we prove this inequality for  for all $x,y,z \geq 0$?

We need to prove:

$$27(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq 64(xy+yz+zx)^3$$

Expanding directly leads to a very complicated expression, and overall this inequality is a little tight. I have not been able to prove it by AM-GM or Cauchy.

Comment: Try things like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_inequalities, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin%27s_inequality, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality

Comment: @frank000, thanks, these are very useful for my other, more general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a simple and nice proof of
$$27(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq 64(xy+yz+zx)^3 \quad \forall x,y,z \ge 0.$$

Indeed, it is straightforward to see that the above inequality follows directly from
\begin{equation}
9(x+y)(y+z)(z+x) \ge 8(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx) \quad (1)
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
(x+y+z)^2 \ge 3(xy+yz+zx) \quad (2)
\end{equation}
To prove $(1)$, just notice that 
$$LHS - RHS = \sum x(y^2+z^2) - 6xyz = \sum x(y-z)^2 \ge 0.$$

**Remark.** From the proof, we have 
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}}{2} \geq \sqrt[3]{\frac{(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)}{9}} \geq \sqrt{\frac{xy+yz+zx}{3}}.$$

Comment: Nice proof indeed, thank you.

Comment: Note that your $(1)$ has another simple proof. Rewrite it as: $$9(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)-9xyz \geq 8(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$$ Now we need to prove: $$(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx) \geq 9xyz$$ But this immediately follows from Caushy-Schwarz inequality

Comment: @YuriyS Sorry I didn't notice your comment. I just came back here after an upvote. In my opinion, the proof of (1) that I gave above is already the simplest, no known inequality is involved except $a^2 \ge 0$ ;)

Comment: Khue, fair enough

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that I appreciate that you managed to squeeze another expression between the two :)

Comment: @YuriyS Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First we prove a very close inequality:

> $$27(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq 63(xy+yz+zx)^3+27x^2y^2z^2$$

The proof is as follows. By direct expansion we see:

$$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)=(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)-xyz$$

---

$$(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2= \\ =(x+y+z)^2(xy+yz+zx)^2-2xyz(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)+x^2y^2z^2$$

Using Cauchy-Schwartz we can transform the second term:

$$(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx) \geq 9xyz$$

---

$$(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq \\ \geq (x+y+z)^2(xy+yz+zx)^2-\frac{2}{9}(x+y+z)^2(xy+yz+zx)^2+x^2y^2z^2$$

---

$$(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq \frac{7}{9}(x+y+z)^2(xy+yz+zx)^2+x^2y^2z^2= \\ = \frac{7}{9}(x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+xz))(xy+yz+zx)^2+x^2y^2z^2 \geq \\ \geq \frac{7}{3}(xy+yz+zx)^3+x^2y^2z^2$$

Finally we get:

$$3(x+y)^2(y+z)^2(z+x)^2 \geq 7(xy+yz+zx)^3+3x^2y^2z^2$$

---

**Now we prove the original inequality.**

First, let's get back and rearrange the original equality we used:

$$(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)+xyz=(x+y+z)(xy+yz+zx)$$

Now let's square this and denote:

$$A=(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)$$

$$B=(xy+yz+zx)$$

---

$$A^2+2xyzA+x^2y^2z^2=(x+y+z)^2B^2$$

$$A^2=(x+y+z)^2B^2-2xyzA-x^2y^2z^2 \geq 3B^3-\frac{2}{\sqrt{27}} \sqrt{B^3} A-A^2+\frac{7}{3}B^3$$

> $$A^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{27}} \sqrt{B^3} A-\frac{8}{3}B^3 \geq 0 \tag{1}$$

Here we used the inequality from the previous section and two well known inequalities:

$$x^2y^2z^2 \leq A^2-\frac{7}{3}B^3$$

$$27x^2y^2z^2 \leq B^3$$

$$(x+y+z)^2 \geq 3B$$

$(1)$ is a quadratic inequality, and is easily solved:

> $$A \geq \frac{8}{\sqrt{27}} \sqrt{B^3}$$

The original inequality obviously follows.